# Can anyone understand why my USB 1.1 full speed HUB not work, electronic issue

Tags: usb

Our USB ports design include one USB transiever(STOTG04EQTR) and USB HUB(TUSB2036VF).The circuit drawing as below
[image]

But even the USB1.1 doesn't work. I tested the data line , the waveform really bad as below
[image]
[image]

I did not found any layout problem and we ask the USB differential pair 90 ohm as well(Not sure if the factory really followed)

[image]

Thanks

Hui

Answer (score 1):

The downstream pulldown resistors \$R_{PD}=15 k\Omega\$ are missing for the USB data lines. These are required for correct bus state when neither host nor device are driving the bus.